# How to set Try/Except timeout to find element in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python Selenium to crawl several web pages, and I previously know that some of the pages don't have all elements.

I am already waiting for the page to load and using try/except to find the element (class xyz, for example), and it takes **30 seconds** to get into the exception.

```
try:
    xyz = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.xyz').text
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("\tError finding xyz...")
```

How can I set a smaller timeout, like 5 seconds for example, to be the maximum time for Selenium to look for the element before running the exception and moving on the the next page?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't read the question carefully. It was for Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the WebDriverWait and ExceptionCondition to achieve this.

you need below imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Script:**

```
try:
    xyz = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.xyz'))).text
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("\tError finding xyz...")
```

Comment: It would be more better if you added some explanation

Comment: @suppuruti thanks for the reply, however, it is not working. Since I'm not waiting the the element to be loaded on the page, because depending on the page, the element doesn't exist, it is still taking 30 seconds before it runs into the exception.

Comment: Do you have the `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` somewhere in you code?

Comment: @supputuri that was in fact the issue. Had set up in a separate part of the code and didn't realize it would run for the search of each element. Thought it would run only once on the page loading and not on each search. Thanks!